# How to import cython function to cython script

Tags: python, import, cython

Let us have script foo.pyx with function in it:

```
def hello():
    cdef int* i = <int *> malloc(sizeof(int))
    i[0] = 1
    trol(i)
    print i
```

and script with function noo.pyx:

```
cdef trol(int * i):
    i[0] = 42
```

the question is, how do I now import the trol function from file noo.pyx to foo.pyx, so I can use it in hello function.

This is only model example, but I think, that it illustrate the problem fair enough.

I tried simple

```
from noo import trol
```

but that throws "Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object"

**Edit:** I would better add, that this example will work just fine if I put both functions to same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution eventually was to create additional **.pxd** file, which something very similar to classic header .h file in C. It stores functions declarations and when cimport is called, it is in this file where it looks for functions and structures.

So to be specific, all I needed to do was to create file noo.pxd containing:

```
cdef trol(int * i)
```

and than we can simply cimport this function from foo.pyx by calling

```
from noo cimport trol
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something obvious to try, but did you try:

```
from noo cimport trol
```

If you use `import` instead of `cimport`, I think it will try to cast `trol` as a python function and generate the error you're getting.